# dojox.grid.DataGrid not rendering inside contentpane using attr

Tags: dojox.grid.datagrid

i have a problem using dojox.grid.DataGrid, im using this code to load inside dojox.layout.ContentPane, sadly in IE7 and IE8 doesnt work, but in firefox 3.6 does work perfectly.

```
function getHTML(URL, dest) {
    var myCp= dijit.byId(destino);
    myCp.destroyDescendants(); 
    myCp.attr("href", URL);`
```

This is my first time using Dojo 1.4.2, i took this from dojoexplorer site, i been looking for a solution. i use this code to span the loaded code

```
<div id="mainTabContainer" dojoType="dijit.layout.TabContainer" region="center">
          <div id="LoaderX" dojoType="dojox.layout.ContentPane" title="Welcome"  selected="true" closable="false" href="app/general/content/cd.jsp" executeScripts="true"></div></div>
```

This is how i call the js

```
onclick="getHTML('app/adm/div/form.jsp','LoaderX')"
```

And finally, how i show the grid inside form.jsp

```
        <span dojoType="dojo.data.ItemFileWriteStore" jsId="store3" url="/telsap/port/app/adm/zone/rt.jsp" >
```

and

```
<table dojoType="dojox.grid.DataGrid" loadingMessage="Lopading..." columnReordering="true" jsId="grid3" store="store3" query="{ ypnum_zone: '*' }" rowsPerPage="30" clientSort="true"  rowSelector="20px" >
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th width="100px" field="zone">Zone</th>
        <th width="300px" field="dep" >Department</th>
        <th width="auto" field="city" >City</th>
        <th width="auto" field="mng" >Managment</th>
        <th width="auto" field="state" >State</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
```

I know it must be something i dont see, im new to dojo, thanks for ur help